# ImageLine, imagecreatetruecolor not working properly

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to use the GD image library but no success. All codes I tried always displays the same small empty image. I already checked and GD is enabled. Folder permissions are set to 777 just in case. Im using:

OS: Mac El Capitan,
Server: MAMP, 
PHP ver: 7.0.10.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
$size = 600;
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,$size,$size,$white);

function Vector($palette,$startx,$starty,$angle,$length,$colour){
    $angle = deg2rad($angle);
    $endx = $startx+cos($angle)*$length;
    $endy = $starty-sin($angle)*$length;
    return(imageline($palette,$startx,$starty,$endx,$endy,$colour));
}

Vector($img,$size/2,$size/2,30,200,$black);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code to the top of the page and it works. I don't know why it does not work inside the html, possibly the header? humm, I had moved just the header to the top before but it still didn't work. I have to read more about the library anyways.